# Ef6 select returns nothing after simple select FirstOrDefault()

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an EF6 context with data access that all seem to work. There is one that returns can not evaluate expression. It's a FirstOrDefault. If I do the query without FIrstOrDefault, the IEnumerable contains the 1 item I'm looking for. Where am I going wrong? I have many other FirstOrDefault that work fine.

```
var a = "";
var products = from p in _db.Products
               where p.SKU == isbn
               select p;

foreach (var productx in products)
{
    a = productx.SKU; <- productx contains the valid product
}

var product = (from p in _db.Products
               where p.SKU == isbn
               select p).FirstOrDefault(); <-- can't evaluate
```

The same happens even if I refresh the context ....

These both return the proper row in LinqPad ...

```
Products.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.SKU == "9781250033697")

(from p in Products where p.SKU == "9781250033697" select p).FirstOrDefault()
```

These yield null in my app ( isbn = "9781250033697")

```
var product = _db.Products.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.SKU == isbn);

            var products = from p in _db.Products
                where p.SKU == "9781250033697"
                select p;
```

Other Ling queries against the same db yield valid data.

Comment: In LINQPPad can you query two records one that works with your application and the rebel one, if you compare the values in the fields are they what you are expecting, also while debugging does the output window have any messages when trying to load ["9781250033697"]

Answer (score 0):

```
var product = db.Products.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.SKU == isbn);
```

Comment: Both
    (from p in Products where p.SKU == "9781250033697" select p).FirstOrDefault()
and
    Products.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.SKU == "9781250033697")

Comment: I just added extension to my question. I'm running out of things to try. Thanks SOFKING

Answer (score 0):

With LINQPad

This works

```
/* all records */
var query = (from r in Regions select r);
query.Dump();

/* first record */
var query2 = (from r in Regions select r).FirstOrDefault();
query2.Dump();

/* "00006" record */
var query3 = (from r in Regions where r.MaestroId == "00006" select r).FirstOrDefault();
query3.Dump();
```

I would suggest getting LINQPad and test the expected results outside of the application, to see if the query really return nothing or as you mention can't evaluate.  Hardcode the value of the ISBN you are trying to get, I found out that often when the LINQ queries are not working it's the values I pass to it that are the culprit... unless EF6 changed completly ...

Answer (score 0):

look at the SQL query generated by using the log functionality of entity framework 6

look at this article to know how; [Logging and Intercepting Database Operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464)

it should be that easy;

```
using (var context = new BlogContext()) 
{ 
    context.Database.Log = Console.Write; 

    // Your code here... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to close this.

Thanks for the replies.

I think there is a corrupted source file somewhere in my project. When I run the query in a console project, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue recently and after more than 3 hours of fruitless debugging and checking generated SQL in profiler, I realized that I had an incorrect database specified as "**Initial Catalog**" in my connection string.

Apparently EF can still assemble the right query but it fails to map the results to the model (I think) when the actual database does not match Initial Catalog.

Trivial error but really hard to find since EF does not throw any Exception in such case.

Comment: They are successfully able to retrieve some data, so it's unlikely that it's caused by the connection string.